# ASP.NET-MVC4 - Linq query to select largest "supplier" in a database

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

i have 2 tables in a database

supplier table: SupplierID - SupplierName

product table: ProductID - ProductName - UnitsInStock - SupplierID

how can i select the supplier that has largest UnitsInStock?

here's the code i have

```
    private storeDBEntities2 db1 = new storeDBEntities2();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var product = db1.Products.Where(e => e.UnitsInStock == 0);
        var largestSupplier = db1.Products.GroupBy(e => e.SupplierID);
        Product minimord = db1.Products.OrderBy(e => e.UnitsOnOrder).FirstOrDefault();

        var supplier = // this is the query i am struggling with

        AllModelsProduct all = new AllModelsProduct { Iproduct = product.ToList(), product = new Product(),largestSupplierOfTheStore = supplier,minimumOrders = minimord };
        return View(all);
    }
```

here's a picture of my data

[image]

i need to get supplierID 345 as we have 20 units belong to him in store which is greater than the other supplier with 5 + 3 + 0 = 8 units

Comment: Do you have some code you can show us?

Comment: Looking at your table schema, you can't.  Your product table would need a SupplierID foreign key.

Comment: Which table have data of which supplier supplies which product? What query you are trying to get the result? Can you share sample input data and expected output?

Comment: i edited the question with code and added supplierId foreign key.

Comment: db1.Products.OrderByDescending(e => e.UnitsOnOrder).Take(1).Select(e => e.Supplier).FirstOrDefault();?  Coudn't you just do something like that?

Comment: the supplier can supply with multiple products. check the question i added a picture of the data

Comment: i believe it can be done in linq only by joining and grouping but if you have another approach post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you're looking to do is find the supplier with the largest number of `UnitsInStock` then this should do the trick.

I have created a [dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/askbsL) for you to observe.

But here it is anyway:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Supply> lstSuppliers = new List<Supply>();
        Supply supply1 = new Supply() { ID = 1, SupplierName = "Supplier One"};
        Supply supply2 = new Supply() { ID = 2, SupplierName = "Supplier Two"};

        lstSuppliers.Add(supply1);
        lstSuppliers.Add(supply2);

        Product product1 = new Product() {ID = 1, UnitsInStock = 3, SupplierID = 1};
        Product product2 = new Product() {ID = 2, UnitsInStock = 3, SupplierID = 2};
        Product product3 = new Product() {ID = 3, UnitsInStock = 5, SupplierID = 1};

        List<Product> lstAllProducts = new List<Product>();
        lstAllProducts.Add(product1);
        lstAllProducts.Add(product2);
        lstAllProducts.Add(product3);

        var findSupplierId = lstAllProducts.GroupBy(x => x.SupplierID).Select(x => new{ Supplier = x.Key.ToString(), Count = x.Sum(g => g.UnitsInStock)}).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count).First().Supplier;

        Console.WriteLine(findSupplierId);



        Console.WriteLine(lstSuppliers.Single(x => x.ID.ToString() == findSupplierId).SupplierName);

    }
}

public class Supply{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string SupplierName {get;set;}
}

public class Product{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public int UnitsInStock {get;set;}
    public int SupplierID {get;set;}
}
```

This uses the `GroupBy`, along with creating anonymous classes to get the desired outcome.

Let me know if this helps!

**Update - To show if multiple suppliers have the same units in stock**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Supply> lstSuppliers = new List<Supply>();
        Supply supply1 = new Supply() { ID = 1, SupplierName = "Supplier One"};
        Supply supply2 = new Supply() { ID = 2, SupplierName = "Supplier Two"};
        Supply supply3 = new Supply() { ID = 3, SupplierName = "Supplier Three"};

        lstSuppliers.Add(supply1);
        lstSuppliers.Add(supply2);
        lstSuppliers.Add(supply3);

        Product product1 = new Product() {ID = 1, UnitsInStock = 3, SupplierID = 1};
        Product product2 = new Product() {ID = 2, UnitsInStock = 3, SupplierID = 2};
        Product product3 = new Product() {ID = 3, UnitsInStock = 5, SupplierID = 1};
        Product product4 = new Product() {ID = 4, UnitsInStock = 8, SupplierID = 3};

        List<Product> lstAllProducts = new List<Product>();
        lstAllProducts.Add(product1);
        lstAllProducts.Add(product2);
        lstAllProducts.Add(product3);
        lstAllProducts.Add(product4);

        // finds largest supplier
        //var findSupplierId = lstAllProducts.GroupBy(x => x.SupplierID).Select(x => new{ Supplier = x.Key.ToString(), Count = x.Sum(g => g.UnitsInStock)}).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count).First().Supplier;
        //Console.WriteLine(lstSuppliers.Single(x => x.ID.ToString() == findSupplierId).SupplierName);

        // What if there are multiple suppliers with the same number of units in stock?

        // first - we have to find the largest number of units in stock
        var findLargestNumberUIS = lstAllProducts.GroupBy(x => x.SupplierID).Select(x => new{ Supplier = x.Key.ToString(), Count = x.Sum(g => g.UnitsInStock)}).Max(x => x.Count); // 8

        // second - gather a list of suppliers where their units in stock == findLargestNumberUIS
        var lstOfLargestSuppliers = lstAllProducts.GroupBy(x => x.SupplierID).Select(x => new{ Supplier = x.Key.ToString(), Count = x.Sum(g => g.UnitsInStock)}).Where(x => x.Count == findLargestNumberUIS).ToList();

        // third - loop through lstOfLargestSuppliers to get all suppliers that have the same amount of units in stock which happen to be the largest
        foreach(var item in lstOfLargestSuppliers){
            var supplier = lstSuppliers.Single(x => x.ID.ToString() == item.Supplier).SupplierName;
            Console.WriteLine(supplier); // print the supplier names to console

            // Output - Supplier One
            //          Supplier Three
        }



    }
}

public class Supply{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string SupplierName {get;set;}
}

public class Product{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public int UnitsInStock {get;set;}
    public int SupplierID {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: the .toString gave me an error i jut removed it and worked perfectly Thank you

Comment: I just updated my answer to show the scenario if you were to have 2 suppliers that have the same amount of units in stock, and that number were to be the largest.

Comment: what would happen if we had 2 suppliers with qual unitsinstock? would it produce an error ?

Comment: If you were using my first solution - no it would not produce an error.. rather it would only return the **first** supplier in the list that has the largest number of units in stock.. so, if there were 2 suppliers that had equal units in stock.. the first solution would only return the 1st supplier that it finds in the list.. my second solution includes **all** suppliers that have an equal amount of unitsinstock and that number happens to be the largest

Comment: yes i just tried to produce this scenario and no error happened and it returned the 1st supplier as you mentioned. Thank you